# Can I make a Single Logout from WSO2 Identity Server using POST not Redirect?

Tags: post, wso2, logout, saml, wso2-identity-server

Can I make a Single Logout from WSO2 Identity Server using POST not Redirect?
I keep getting the following message:

> No established Sessions corresponding to the Session Indexes provided

After some debugging I found out that the session index is obtained by a corresponding `sessionID`. This session ID is obtained from a cookie named `samlssoTOkenId`. The thing is that when I am sending a POST to the Identity Provider, I do not have this cookie - I can set it up manually but I do not know its value.

My questions are:

1. Is this appraoch even possible - using POST not REDIRECT?
2. Is there some configuration on the Identity Provider which will search for the session index in the request itself not using the cookie approach?
3. Is it possible to somehow obtain the value of this session ID - when receiving the response after authentication or some other means?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

With WSO2IS 4.5.0 and latest versions `SessionIndex` attribute is returned with the SAML2 Response. Here, You need to enable the `Enable Single Logout`  when service provider is registered in WSO2IS.  Also all Single logout requests are handled with respect to the `SessionIndex` attribute not with the "samlssoTOkenId". As i understood it is invalid to use the cookie values as `SessionIndex`.  But there is no way to configure POST and Redirect. I guess currently it is only supported for Post. Please find the more details about single logout implementation from [here](http://soasecurity.org/2013/06/28/how-saml2-single-logout-works/). This blog is true with the WSO2IS as well

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Unfortunately the implementation of WSO2 Identity Server tries to get the value of the cookie "samlssoTokenId" and based on this value. obtains the session index. If I provide the session idnex as part of my request there is no change - I keep getting the same error - simply because it looks like the IDp will always look for this cookie.

Comment: What is WSO2 IS version that you are using? BTW you mean about the SAML Authentication in WSO2IS  or SAML IDP implementations..  Basically you are sending SAML response to IS or getting SAML response from IS?

Comment: WSO2 IS version is 4.6.0. I mean the implementation behind SAML IDP - WSO2IS in particular. I send my Single Logout Request to the WSO2 Identity Provider, the request is received but I get the above message about session indexes. The problem is that my request is not processed because of missing Session Index. My research shows that in WSO2IS the vlaue of the cookie samlssoTOkenId is obtained, then a session idnex is found on the provider correspondign to this ID and this is the Session Index used. The Session Index in the requested is not taken into consideration.